# exclude fields in $lookup aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am querying between 3 collections I want to exclude `_id` everywhere in output

**My output is:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6aed5f9bcdb5d4ae64aef5"),
    "userID" : "1",
    "skills" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b766b5f1365a4940bb6050f"),
            "skillID" : "javaid",
            "skillname" : "जावा",
            "languageID" : "hindiid"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b766b8c1365a4940bb60535"),
            "skillID" : "pythonid",
            "skillname" : "पायथन",
            "languageID" : "hindiid"
        }
    ],

    "gender" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b7687cd2a2329043e2383d5"),
        "genderID" : "femaleid",
        "gendername" : "महिला",
        "languageID" : "hindiid"
    }
}
```

**Query:**

```
db.User.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "userID":"1" }},
  { "$lookup":{
    "from": "Skill",
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "languageID": "hindiid", "skillID": { "$in": [ "javaid","pythonid" ] }}},
    ],
    "as": "skills"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "Gender",
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "languageID": "hindiid", "genderID" : "femaleid" }},
    ],
    "as": "gender"
  }},
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$gender", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true }},
  { "$project": { "userID": 1, "skills": 1, "gender": 1 }}
])
```

In output for every object has `_id`.Example for `skill` list every object has `_id` i want exclude `_id` field every where. How I can exclude?

Comment: can you post your query please?

Comment: you must use $project: {"_id":0} to specifically remove _id from the results.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In mongodb **3.6** you can use projection ([**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/))  inside [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) pipeline... Something like this

```
db.User.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "userID":"1" }},
  { "$lookup":{
    "from": "Skill",
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "languageID": "hindiid", "skillID": { "$in": [ "javaid","pythonid" ] }}},
      { "$project": { "_id": 0 }}
    ],
    "as": "skills"
  }}
])
```