# Join another collection on $lookup with $mergedObject query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this query which uses MongoDB's left join. I want to add another $lookup but I cant seem to make it work when I put it before the $lookup which has the $mergeObjects.

```
db.getCollection("coverages").aggregate([
        {
        $lookup: {
            from: "filings",
            let: { coverageRepoNo: "$RepoNo" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$RepoNum", "$$coverageRepoNo"] }
                    }
                },
                { $sort: { PeriodEndDate: -1, SubType: 1 } },
                { $group: { _id: "$RepoNum", data: { $first: "$$ROOT" } } },
                { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }
            ],
            as: "fromItems"
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                    { $arrayElemAt: ["$fromItems", 0], },
                    "$$ROOT"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    { $project: { fromItems: 0, __v: 0, _id: 0 } }
])
```

I want to add another $lookup. Where do I put the $lookup with these properties?

```
$lookup: {
            from: "analysts",
            localField: "AnalystID", // field in the coverages collection
            foreignField: "AnalystID", // field inthe analysts collection
            as: "fromAnalysts"
        }
```

hey @AnthonyWinzlet here is a sample data when I put the lookup in the firstline

```
{ 
"AnalystID" : "JDO", 
"AnalystName" : "John Doe", 
"AnalystLocationName" : "California", 
"fromAnalysts" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b84a79135da280d88858a13"), 
        "AnalystID" : "JDO", 
        "AnalystName" : "John Doe", 
        "AnalystLocationName" : "California",
        "TLName": "Foo Bar"
    }
]}
```

I only want the "TLName" to show after the "AnalystLocationName". How can I do that?

Comment: could you elaborate your question... Where do you want to add one more `$lookup` stage?

Comment: hi @AnthonyWinzlet. I want to add the lookup in the first stage. Am I correct?

Comment: You can add one more `$lookup` as you did above... Ok please post your sample collections and  the output

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950121/exclude-fields-in-lookup-aggregation/51950262#51950262