# MongoDB lookup and then project

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I have two collections -- **`jobs`** and **`companies`** -- that have a many-to-one relationship such that many **`jobs`** exist for one **`companies`** record.

**`jobs`** has the following fields:

> job_id, company_id, last_updated, j_foo, j_bar

**`companies`** has the following fields:

> company_id, name, some_url, c_foo, c_bar

The query I have right now:

```js
var matchObj = {'company_id':'some_company'};
var lookupObj = {from:'companies',localField:'company_id',foreignField:'company_id',as:'company_info'};
var projectObj = {'job_id':1,'company_id':1,'last_updated':1};
var sortObj = {'last_updated':-1};

jobs.aggregate({$match:queryObj},{$lookup:queryLookup},{$project:queryProject},{$sort:sortObj}).toArray(function(err,results){
  doSomething();
});
```

returns more data than I need:

```js
[
  {
    job_id: val,
    company_id: val,
    last_updated: date,
    j_foo: val,
    j_bar: val,
    company_info: [{ 
      company_id: val, name: val, some_url: val, c_foo: val, c_bar: val
    }]  // I don't want company_info as an array ideally,
        // rather just have the object since it's a to-one relationship
        // it's always just one result. This isn't critical,
        // just would be a nicety if you can help with this too
  },
  {
    job_id: val,
    company_id: val,
    last_updated: date,
    j_foo: val,
    j_bar: val,
    company_info: [{ 
      company_id: val, name: val, some_url: val, c_foo: val, c_bar: val
    }]
  }
]
```

what I want the output to be is:

```js
[
  {
    job_id: val,
    company_id: val,
    last_updated: date,
    company_info: { 
      name: val, some_url: val
    }
  },
  {
    job_id: val,
    company_id: val,
    last_updated: date,
    company_info: { 
      name: val, some_url: val
    }
  }
]
```

I would also be ok if the output was:

```js
[
  {
    job_id: val,
    company_id: val,
    last_updated: date,
    company_name: val,
    company_some_url: val
  },
  {
    job_id: val,
    company_id: val,
    last_updated: date,
    company_name: val,
    company_some_url: val
  }
]
```

How do I project the lookup query? Or is there another way using $addFields?

Comment: Use `$unwind` with the `company_info` field after the `$lookup` stage. Something like `{ "$unwind": "$company_info"}`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet my understanding is unwind will deconstruct the array, but as you see in my post, this is a minor nice to have kind of thing. The main point is I need to return only two of the fields in the **`companies`** table, and with $lookup I'm getting them all. Ideas?

Comment: You can use newer `$lookup` syntax to exclude the fields inside the pipeline. [exclude fields in $lookup aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950121/exclude-fields-in-lookup-aggregation)

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet thanks for the help, but we're still not there. If I remove all sorting and projecting from the **`jobs`** table, then the `$lookup` pipeline works. So this `$projects` the **`companies`** table: `db.getCollection('jobs').aggregate({$match:{'company_id’:’some_company’}},{$lookup:{from:'companies',pipeline: [{$match:{'company_id':'some_company'}},{$project:{‘some_url’:1,’name’:1}},],as:'company_info'}});` However if I try to `project` the results from **`jobs`** now, the `$lookup` doesn't work.