# How to retrieve only few fields from another collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I have two collection

Collection_foo :

```
{
    cid:'1234',
    'foo':'bar',
    some 10+ fields...
}
```

Collection_bar :

```
{
    cid:'1234',
    'foobar':'barfoo',
    some 10+ fields...
}
```

I want to join this collection

I tried using $lookup, $unwind, $project

```
aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: 'Collection_bar',
            localField: 'cid',
            foreignField: 'cid',
            as: 'collection_foo_bar',
        }
    },
    { $unwind :'collection_foo_bar' },
    { 
        $project : {
             'foobar':'collection_foo_bar.foobar', 
             collection_foo_bar : 0 //
        }
    }
])
```

I have also tried this but got error

```
{ 
    $project : {
        'foobar':'collection_foo_bar.foobar', 
        collection_foo_bar : 0 
    }
}
```

Now i got

```
{
    'foobar':'barfoo'

}
```

Where I wanted this

```
{
    cid:'1234',
    'foo':'bar',
    some 10+ fields...,
    'foobar':'barfoo'
}
```

Only 1 field from 2nd collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exclude fields in $lookup aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950121/exclude-fields-in-lookup-aggregation)

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet that doesnt really help me

Comment: What version of mongo you are using?

Comment: MongoDB shell version v4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, please.
Variant 1.

```
db.Collection_foo.aggregate([
    {
    $lookup:{
        from: "Collection_bar",
        localField: "cid",
        foreignField:"cid",
        as: "collection_foo_bar"
    },  
    },
    { $unwind :'$collection_foo_bar' },      
   {
      $replaceRoot: { 
          newRoot: { 
              $mergeObjects: [ "$$ROOT",{foobar:"$collection_foo_bar.foobar"}] 
          } 
      }
   },   
   { $project: { collection_foo_bar: 0 } }

])
```

Variant 2

```
db.Collection_foo.aggregate([
    {
    $lookup:{
        from: "Collection_bar",
        localField: "cid",
        foreignField:"cid",
        as: "collection_foo_bar"
    },  
    },
    { $unwind :'$collection_foo_bar' },      
   {
      $addFields: {foobar:"$collection_foo_bar.foobar"}
   },   
   { $project: { collection_foo_bar: 0 } }
])
```

The result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c51a1479b70d343fb47d3ae"),
    "cid" : "1234",
    "foo" : "bar",
    "f1" : 1.0,
    "f23" : 2,
    "f33" : 3,
    "foobar" : "barfoo1111"
}
```

where "foobar" from second collection and other fields from first collection.