# MongoDB $lookup aggregation - Retrieve only one single field from document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Here's my aggregation. I would want to only get one field from the resulting JSON not whole document.

```
 Listings.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "userid",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "user"
        }
    },  
    { $sort : { _id : -1 } }
]).exec(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            title: 'An error occurred',
            error: err
        });
    }
    res.json(data);
});
```

Here's the resulting JSON I'm getting from the request.

```
{
   _id: "5c8b5c148ee19c6a092a76fe",
   name: "Brian Ken",
   email: "brian@kena.com",
   pass: "sdlajsdlj99939*&*&sdsdljsjdljllj"
}
```

Ideally I would only like to pull only the email field and not everything from this document. I hope my explanation is satisfactory. Anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exclude fields in $lookup aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950121/exclude-fields-in-lookup-aggregation)

Comment: I think they are abit different, also can you help with this?

Comment: Please try to go through the above answer it is same as your posted question. If you  need any help then let me know I will surely help you

Comment: I've tried to replicate your answer from the other response - I get an error 500

            `$lookup: {
                from: "uploads",
                pipeline: [
                    { "$match": { "uuid" : "uuid" }},
                    { "$project": { "_id": 0 }}
                ],
                as: "uploads"
            }`

Comment: try this `{ $lookup: {
     from: "users",
     let: { userId: '$userId' },
     pipeline: [
      { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$$userId', '$_id'] }}},
      { $project: { email: 1 }}
     ],
     as: "user"
    }}`

Answer (score 0):

Follow up after the $sort pipeline with a $project pipeline

```
.
.   // SORT
.
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        name: 0,
        email: 1,
        pass: 0
    }
}
```

> In $project, **0** means to now show that field in the result, and **1** is to show

You study more about $project from the [MongoDB's official website](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)